# Can anyone help me shorten this absurdly long selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

EDIT: Skip to end for a better explanation of what I'm after, thx

I have approximately the following html (this just an excerpt) where there is a nested organisation of chapters:

```
<span class="chapter Art" id="00034">
  <li><span class="chapterheading">Art<span>some stuff</span></li>
  <ul>
    <span class="chapter" id="00035">
      <li><span class="chapterheading selectednode">Sound</span><span>more stuff</span></li>
      <div class="idea">even more stuff</div>
    </span>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Now I wish to use javascript to show only the immediately below chapter headings, and immediately below div's of class 'idea', such that to see any 'idea' you have to click on the immediate parent chapter of it.

After about three hours spent (because i'm a bit green with jquery and it took me a while to realise how the child selector really worked), I came up with a really convoluted query that does what I want in terms of showing the relevent nodes (assume that they are hidden prior to running this code):

```
t.find("li > *, ul > .chapter, ul > .chapter > li, ul > .chapter > li *, > .idea, > .idea *").show();
```

where 't' is the most recently clicked node which has class 'selectednode' (EDIT: is the parent of the parent of that node).

So is there a much shorter way of expressing what I need here?

Edit: The following is a much bigger code snip as requested with a lot of baggage.  Look for the comment "hide children of sibling chapters of the same depth."

I've since pruned it a bit but it doesn't do what I want: I cannot get it to show *just* the immediate chapters and ideas below, it shows everything.

```
function toggleNode(node, value) {
    //_("setting " + nv(node) + " to " + value + "\n");
    $(node).toggleClass("selectednode", value);
    if($(node).hasClass("selectednode") == true)
    selectednode = node;
    if($(selectednode).hasClass("selectednode") == false) // is this check really necessary?
    selectednode = 0;
}


function zoomTo(node, select) {
    var zoom, oldzoom, depth, t;
    //_("zoomTo(" + (node ? $(node).text() : "0") + ", " + select + ")");
    oldzoom = zoomednode;
    if(node != zoomednode) {
    savedepth = t = depth = $(node).parents("ul").length;
    if(!zoomednode)
        zoomednode = topChapter;
    if(!node)
        node = topChapter;
    /* capture values */
    var sz;
    var capp = cBaseSz.slice((sz = parseFloat(cBaseSz)).length);
    /* end capture */
    zoom = zoomnum = sz;
    while(--t > 0) {
            zoomnum = (zoom *= 1.15);
    }
    //_("zoom: " + zoomnum +"\ncapp: " +capp);
    zoom  += capp;
    //_("zoom: " + zoomnum);
    depth -= $(zoomednode).parents("ul").length;
    if(depth < 0)
        depth *= -1;
    switch(select) {
    case 0:
    case false:
    default:
        break;
    case true:
    case 1:
        toggleNode(zoomednode, false);
        toggleNode(zoomednode = node, true);
        break;
    case 2:
        toggleNode(zoomednode, false);
            zoomednode = 0;
    }

    /* Handle showing/hiding */

    if(1) {
        var hide;
        t = ($(selectednode) || $(".chapterheading:first"));
        _("t.text():" + t.text());
        t = t.parent().parent();
        _("isclass: " + t.attr("class"));
        var prs = $(t).parents(".chapter");
        prs = $(prs)[0] || t;
        hide = $(prs).siblings(".chapter");
        _("topparent: " + $(prs).text().slice(0,80));
        $(hide).each( function() { {
        _(($(this).html()||$(this).text()).slice(0, 80));
        }});
        $("li *, > ul, > idea", t).show();
        //t.siblings().show();
        //t.siblings().find().hide();
        //hide.children(".chapterheading").find().show();
        //showall(t.find("li *, ul > .chapter > li *"));

        // Hide deeper children of this chapter (t) 
//      $(t).find("ul *:not(ul > .chapter > li, ul > li *)").hide();
//      t.find("li > *, ul > .chapter, ul > .chapter > li, ul > .chapter > li *, > .idea, > .idea *").show();
        // Show immediate children of this chapter (t)
        //$(t).find("> li *, ul > .chapter").show();
       // t.find(".chapterheading, .ideacount").show();
        //$(hide).children().find(":not(.chapterheading, .ideacount)").hide();



        // Hide children of sibling chapters of the same depth.
        $("ul > .chapter", t).hide();
        // Hide children of siblings of the top-most parent chapter of the selected chapter.
        $("ul > .chapter, ul > .chapter .chapter", hide).hide();
        // Show the selected chapter
        $("ul > .chapter, ul > chapter .chapter", t.parent()).show();
        }

    //////////////////////////////
     // old version below, but keeping for reference
    else {
    var showzoom = 1, showselect = 1, showidea = 1, seldepth, zdepth, showlist, hidelist = {};
    /* This is the 'brute force' way of doing it, horribly inefficient */
    if(zoomednode)
        zdepth = $(zoomednode).parents(".chapter").length;
    if(selectednode)
        seldepth = $(selectednode).parents(".chapter").length;
    else
        seldepth = zdepth;
    if(!seldepth)
        seldepth = zdepth = 0;
    _("seldepth: " + seldepth + "\nzdepth: " + zdepth);
    (showlist=$(".chapter").filter( function() {
        if($(this).parents(".chapter").length < (zdepth+showzoom))
        return true;
        else {
        hidelist = $(hidelist).add(this);
        return false;
        }
    }));
    //    hidelist = $("all").not(showlist);
    if(hidelist)
        _("hidelist size: " + hidelist.length);
    _("showlist size: " + showlist.length);
    $(showlist).show()/*.not(hidelist)*/;
    if(hidelist && hidelist.length) {
        //_("Hiding " + $(hidelist).length + " elements.");
        $(hidelist).hide();
    }
    }
    /* End showing/hiding */

    /* Begin animating */
    $("#contents").animate({ fontSize: zoom }, {duration: 0, queue: false });
    $("html").animate(
        { scrollTop: $(node).offset().top - topAdjust }, {duration: 60+60*depth, queue: false }, 0);
    $(window).scrollLeft($(node).offset().left - leftAdjust);
    } else {

    zoomTo(0, 1 + (selectednode == zoomednode));
    }
}


function setupEvents() {
    $("#contents .chapterheading").click( function() {  _("\n-- -- -- CLICK -- -- --\n-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --\n"), zoomTo(this, true); });
}
```

EDIT: For further reference, the markup is of the following sort (expressed recursively):

```
<ul> <!-- A: chapter heading list -->
  <span class="chapter">
    <li><span class="chapterheading">Title</span></li>
    <!-- 0 or more of the following --> <div class="idea"><!-- more stuff --></div>
    <!-- 0 or more of A: chapter heading list -->
  </span>
</ul>
```

And, where the variable 't' points to a  the class "selectednode" will also be appended, which is where I wish the following to occur:

1. show all immediate child 'ul' elements, which would also mean the chapter heading underneath that.  But do not show anything below that.
2. hide what is shown for the selected chapter for all sibling chapters.
3. hide what is shown for the selected chapter for all top-most chapters that aren't in the ancestry of the selected chapter.

Comment: _where 't' is the most recently clicked node which has class 'selectednode'._? Does `span.selectednode` _have_ a `li` child to be found? how does this work?

Comment: note that your html is invalid. <ul> can only contain <li>, not <span> or <div> as you have it now. Also <li> has to be a child of <ul> (or <ol>) and not of <span>. Consider fixing your html first, before looking for the best selector...

Comment: Why not take an event based approach? $('.chapterheading').on('click',  callback)

Comment: @PeterVR: Hmm, do you mean that it can't contain elements other than li as immediate children, or it can't contain anything other than li period?

In either case it severely limits what I was planning to do with it.  It's also strange that despite setting the doctype it tolerates my invalid html in all the browsers I've tried...

Comment: @Raminson: That was an error on my part: t is set to t.parent().parent() first.

Comment: Can you show more of your JS? How about the entire click event, so we can see what the context of the var t, is. Also, why are you grabbing children of .selectednode with .find()? All I see in your markup example is text. no li, or nested ul > li...

Comment: @Matthew Blancarte : t points to <span class="chapter Art" id="00034"> I messed up with what I previously said.

Comment: Now I have to come up with a similar selector for hiding.  I have the impression I must be abusing jquery rather than using it effectively if the solutions are looking this inellegant.  Is there no method that hides a node and all its children instead of just the top-most node?

Comment: @RobF: How are the elements hidden at all? I'm quite sure that you will not need to select every single node and call `.show()` on it.

Comment: @RobF: If you hide a Node, all its children will be hidden! It will apply a CSS inline-style of `display:none`

Comment: @Bergi: Seems the reverse isn't true for show()...

Comment: Why have a chapter nested inside a chapter? This is not logical and may well make the selector difficult to phrase. As @PeterVR suggests, the HTML needs fixing before trying to get the jQuery to work. The fact that browsers will render invalid HTML doesn't matter. Fix it!

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I don't know how to fix it without destroying the very concept that I was going for visually.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Why not having subchapters? That would be very logical to me, HTML itselft has 6 levels of headings. But it's true, the OP first needs to learn HTML :-)

Comment: Rob, you've got no choice. Invalid HTML will generate an uncertain DOM tree. Different browsers may make different interpretations. You can't expect javascript/jQuery to to act reliably under these circumstances.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot The DOM has the same structure in the browsers I have tried.  If you don't want to help me with it, fine.  It's not the reason for my problem, so right now I'm not going to worry about it.

Comment: Rob, I am helping. I'm giving you my best advice.

Comment: The html is now legal.  Going to try something @Bergi suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Restructure your HTML to make it valid. My suggestion:

```
<div id="toc">
   <h2>Table of Contents</h2>
   <ul>
      <li id="00034" class="art">
         <span class="chapterheading">Title</span>
         <!-- more stuff -->
         <div class="idea"> ... </div>
         ...
         <ul>
            <li id="00035">
               <span class="chapterheading selected">Subtitle</span>
            </li>
            ...
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span class="chapterheading">Second Title</span>
         ...
      </li>
      ...
   </ul>
</div>
```

This does not use a `chapter` class, it just assumes that all `li` elements in the `#toc` represent a chapter.

With this structure, the built DOM (on which all selectors etc are applied, you can inspect it in the developer console) will look exactly like the HTML markup. In your code, the `span` tags inside the `ul` elements are likely to be moved somewhere into the `li` items.

Now, to hide all the elements that come after a chapterheading we use this code CSS code:

```
#toc li > * {
    display: none;
}
```

but show them if the li is selected:

```
#toc li > span.chapterheading, #toc li.selected > * {
    display: block;
}
```

With Javascript, we now would only need to move the `selected` class acording to the clicks:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toc").on("click", "span.chapterheading", function(ev) {
        $(this).closest("li")
          .addClass("selected")
          .siblings().removeClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Comment: I've legalised the html now, didn't know it was as simple as that.  Will try the css you suggested.  While we're here, is there a good page that documents any other css symbols alongside ~ and * that I might not know about?

Comment: hi, i've adapted your code to mine and the effect it has is that of showing the chapters of 1 depth or less.  If I click into further nested chapters the entire chapter tree dissapears except for the top-most chapters.  It also doesn't hide the ideas that are more than 1 node deep.

Comment: I've read that tilde only selects the next siblings, not previous...?

Comment: Uh, my mistake. Adapted the code for multi-level support :-) And yes, the ~ was intended to select all elements after the heading <span>, which is the first element in the <li>, isn't it?

Comment: @RobF This is good code from bergi. In your selectors within zoomTo way too much is going on and using the jQuery closest selector like bergi has done here. That will get rid of the parent searches you are doing within zoomTo

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're working with because you haven't shown enough code.

Based on your markup pattern and what I think you are doing outside of your one line of JavaScript, here is what I think may work for you:

```
$( '.chapterheading' ).click( function(){
  var t = $( this );
  //I assume you are doing other stuff with t...
  t.parent().next().show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/US4Nr/

Comment: It's not grabbing from a span with no children, I've edited my OP to correct this.

Comment: In order to submit a large block of code is there an easy way to prepend the 4 spaces for formatting a code block or do I have to do this by hand?

Comment: I cannot find the mystery {} button... does it exist in 'add a comment' or do I have to click 'answer your question' ?

Comment: Added even more elaboration to my OP.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative type of list is better suited to this type of problem - namely Definition Lists `<dl>` together with Definition Terms `<dt>` and Definition Descriptions `<dd>`.

HTML :

```
<div id="toc">
    <h2>Table of Contents</h2>
    <dl>
        <dt id="00034">Title 00034</dt>
        <dd class="text">text 00034</dd>
        <dd class="idea">idea 00034</dd>
        <dd class="sub">
            <dl>
                <dt id="00035">Subtitle 0035</dt>
                <dd class="text">text 00035</dd>
                <dd class="idea">idea 00035</dd> 
            </dl>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt id="00036">Title 00036</dt>
        <dd class="text">text 00036</dd>
        <dd class="idea">idea 00036</dd> 
    </dl>
</div>
```

And the javascript :

```
$("#toc dt").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("dl")
        .children(".idea").hide().end()
        .children(".text, .sub").toggle().end()
        .siblings().find("dd").hide();
});

$("#toc dd.text").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("dl").children(".idea").toggle();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BzESv/)**

All control is exercised directly by the javascript. All the CSS in the DEMO is for appearance, not for hiding/showing.

May not be exactly what you want, particularly with regard to how the event handlers are attached, but should give you a good idea of how to approach this.